# What is the name of the binary encoding where 01 stands for 1 and 10 stands for 0

Tags: encoding, binary

The title pretty much says all. What is the name of the binary encoding where 01 stands for 1 and 10 stands for 0, or the other way around?

So

```
  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  becomes:
 01 10 01 10 10 01 01
```

Answer (score 2):

Manchester Encoding see, for instance, [this](https://erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/phy-pages/manc.html).

Answer (score 0):

It’s called Nuding. It’s a form of Offset Binary. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary?wprov=sfti1)